# Qt pushbutton slot called twice, although disabled

Tags: qt, signals, slot, qpushbutton

I have a QPushButton, and a slot connected to its "pressed" signal like that:

```
connect( &m_oBtnSnapshot, SIGNAL( pressed() ), this, 
    SLOT( SnapshotClicked() ) );
```

The Slot is implemented like that:

```
void
GUI::SnapshotClicked()
{
    m_oBtnSnapshot.blockSignals( true );
    m_oBtnSnapshot.setDisabled( true );

    m_oBtnBenchmark.repaint();
    m_oBtnBenchmark.update();


    emit( DoSnapshotWork() );

    m_oBtnSnapshot.setDisabled( false );
    m_oBtnSnapshot.blockSignals( false );
}
```

So as you can see, i disable the button when i click it, and re enable it when everything is done.
Let's assume the DoSnapshotWork() function takes 5 seconds... While this 5 seconds the button is disabled, but if i click it, the SnapshotClicked() Slot will be called afterwards. Why does disabling a button not prevent me from clicking it?

i alread tried disconnecting the signal on entering the slot and reconnecting it afterwards, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GUI::SnapshotClicked()` is a part of GUI thread, which means, while it runs, your GUI is unaccessible. I assume, signal `DoSnapshotWork()` is connected with a slot, running in another thread with `Qt::QueuedConnection` (or `Qt::AutoConnection`). In that case emitting this signal is asynchronous, which means `GUI::SnapshotClicked()` is finished long before your slot is done. I guess you should do something like this:

gui.h

```
public slots:
    void onReleaseButton();
```

gui.cpp

```
void
GUI::SnapshotClicked()
{
    m_oBtnSnapshot.setDisabled( true );

    m_oBtnBenchmark.repaint();
    m_oBtnBenchmark.update();

    emit( DoSnapshotWork() );
}

void
GUI::onReleaseButton()
{
    m_oBtnSnapshot.setDisabled( false );
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
connect(shapshotWorker, SIGNAL(releaseButton()), gui, SLOT(onReleaseButton()));

...

DoSnapshotWork()
{
...

emit releaseButton();
}
```

P.S: You need a good reason to use QPushButton::pressed() signal. In most cases you would prefer QPushButton::clicked().

Comment: why? wheres the difference between pressed and clicked? i did it exactly like you said, but while the button is disabled i am still able to "click" it. It IS disabled, but the DoSnapshotWork() signal is emitted.

Comment: i figured it out now. somehow i missed the Qt::QueuedConnection flag when connecting the DoSnapshotWork() slot to the other thread (where the GUI is, and the button gets pressed). I do not know why, but this somehow caused to call the slot twice. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: `pressed()` is emmitted, when you push down your left mouse button within push button area (and every time, you enter this area afterwards, without releasing mouse button). `clicked()` is emmitted, when you release your left mouse button within push button area, after pushing left button down within it. You can write a simple application to feel the difference. P.S: you are very welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the mouse press events are on placed onto the event loop, and wait until your `SnapshotClicked()` method is complete, by which time the button is enabled again.

A simple solution is to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` immediately after the `emit`, this will cause the press events to processed whilst the button is still disabled.  Or you can have the `DoSnapshotWork()` method emit a signal when it's finished, and have that enable the button and unblock the signals.

Also,

```
m_oBtnBenchmark.repaint();
m_oBtnBenchmark.update();
```

`repaint()`redraws the widget forcibly, whilst `update()` calls `repaint()` via the event loop - do not call them both.

Comment: i tried your processEvents() approach, right behind the emit DoSnapshotWork() and it didn't change anything. But thanks for the hint with repaint and update.